# Layout: 1 TextView top, 2 ListViews middle (50/50), 1 EditText bottom

Tags: android, android-layout

I've been breaking my head over this, but can't seem to figure it out:

I need a TextView on Top, an EditView on bottom and 2 ListViews in the middle (with a 50/50 split of remaining height), where the listviews need to be able to be scrollable for their own content (no scrolling of the screen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/helloworld"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/helloworld"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ListView>
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! I was messing in the wrong place with RelativeLayout

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
  <LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/helloworld"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="185dp"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<ListView
     android:id="@+id/listView1"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="183dp" >
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="184dp"
 android:orientation="horizontal" >
<ListView
     android:id="@+id/listView2"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="190dp" >
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>  
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:ems="10" >
<requestFocus />
</EditText>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```